# Rails - polymorphic paths - indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to learn how to use polymorphic associations in my Rails 5 app.

I have it all plugged in - thanks to this article:  https://rubyplus.com/articles/3901-Polymorphic-Association-in-Rails-5

Now, in my index view I'm trying to make links that filter the index on the basis of one of the attributes in the model.

The polymorphic resource is called package_bips. My package_bips model has:

```
belongs_to :ipable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true #, inverse_of: :bip
```

The package_bips table has an attribute called :status.

In my package/bips/index.html.erb, I'm trying to make links based on the value of status (which is either 'sought' or 'offered').

I'm trying like this:

```
<%= link_to "Offers", polymorphic_path([@ipable, @bips.where(:status => "Offered")]) %>
```

I've also tried making a line in my index action of the bips controller as:

```
@bips_offered = @ipable.bips.where(:status => "Offered")
```

Then in my index I try:

```
<%= link_to "Offers", polymorphic_path(@bips_offered) %>
```

My regular index action works just fine (to show all relevant bips, both sought and offered).

```
<%= link_to "All", action: :index %>
```

I just want links that generate a subset of that group.

Can anyone see how to do that?

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I've tried to use scopes to avoid having to figure out how to give attributes to a polymorphic index path.

I know have these scopes in my bip.rb:

```
scope :offered, -> { where(status: 'Offered') }
scope :sought, -> { where(status: 'Sought') }
```

Then in my bip controller index action, I have:

```
  def index
    @bips = @ipable.bips
    @offered_bips = @ipable.bips.offered
    @sought_bips = @ipable.bips.sought
  end
```

Then in my views/package/bips/index.html.erb, I'm trying:

```
  <%= link_to "Offered", polymorphic_path(@offered_bips) %>
```

The error message, whichever way I try, says:

```
undefined method `to_model' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
Did you mean?  to_xml
```

I don't understand what this error message means (just in english). I think it means that it can't find a model to associate with, but that doesnt make any sense because when I use the @bips line of the index action, I get the right result.

Comment: `@bips.where(:status => "Offered")` generally you can't pass a set of models to a route - only a single model. Perhaps you want to pass a set of bip_ids? in which case - it can't be part of the route, but can be a query-parameter (or form field)

Comment: I have a form field for status - which is set as either sought or offered. I'm trying to figure out how to make links on the index page which can show 1. all status (both sought and offered); 2. offered only, 3. sought only. I could try to find the ids of the instances where status is set to offered or sought but that seems to be doing the same thing as im trying with these attempts

Comment: oh, in which case, you don't need to pass all the offered bips in the route, just the fact that it is offered you're choosing? That just means you need to pass the word "offered" as an argument eg if your normal route was `organisation_bips_path(@organisation)` you'd do `organisation_bips_path(@organisation, :status => 'Offered')` or similar. I'm not sure how to convert that to a polymorphic path, but that's what to start thinking about :)

Answer (score 0):

The polymorphic_path() method also accepts Model class names, see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

polymorphic_path([@ipable,PackageBips])

Should translate to iptable_bips_path(@iptable)